# CUDA: Mitigating the overhead due to multimedia data host-to-device transfers ?

Tags: image-processing, cuda, gpu, multimedia, large-data

I am extracting features from multimedia datasets on host and I want to perform some processing tasks after extracting features from all the images.

In particular, I want to perform sets of operations like distance calculation and preprocessing for database indexing or hashing, possibly accelerated on GPU. However, transferring large-sized feature arrays costs me too much and degrades the performance as compared to sequential processing.

*Can anyone suggest an approach to work with such large data intensive tasks having the need to transfer large datasets ?*

Comment: You can try to overlap memory transfers and computation using async memory transfers and streams, if it is possible for your problem. Have a look at the simpleStreams CUDA SDK example.

Comment: Thank You.I will try this and will try to get optimizations.

Comment: Try to profile the timings.. To which version your comparing its the simple CPU version or you already have some parallel processing like openmp ? You should definitely get better results compared to simple sequential implementation.

Comment: @JackOLantern I think your comment is a sensible, typical approach to handling large data sets.  If you provide that as an answer I would upvote.  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks. I have converted the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The cost of transferring large sized arrays can be hidden by trying to overlap memory transfers and computations by using asynchronous memory copies and streams.

To fully understand how, it would be very useful to have a look at the simpleStreams CUDA SDK example. Here, it is just sketch the general idea.

Let us suppose that the GPU has to perform some operations on two `int` arrays `a` and `b` of lenght `M` by a `__global__` function named `kernel` and that the result, again of length `M`, of such an operation is stored in the array `c`. Assume to create `2` streams, `stream0` and `stream1` and that each stream operates on `M/2` elements. More in detail, each stream loads and process data in chunks of length `M/4`. Let us consider the following code (this code is for illustration only as I have not tested it):

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {

    cudaMemcpyAsync(d_a+i*M/4, h_a+i*M/4, (M/4)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream0));
    cudaMemcpyAsync(d_a+i*M/4+M/2, h_a+i*M/4+M/2, (M/4)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream1));
    cudaMemcpyAsync(d_b+i*M/4, h_b+i*M/4, (M/4)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream0));
    cudaMemcpyAsync(d_b+i*M/4+M/2, h_b+i*M/4+M/2, (M/4)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream1));

    kernel<<<(M/4)/256,256,0,stream0>>>(d_a+i*M/4, d_b+i*M/4, d_c+i*M/4);
    kernel<<<(M/4)/256,256,0,stream1>>>(d_a+i*M/4+M/2, d_b+i*M/4+M/2, d_c+i*M/4+M/2);

    cudaMemcpyAsync(h_c+i*M/4, d_c+i*M/4, (M/4)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream0));
    cudaMemcpyAsync(h_c+i*M/4+M/2, d_c+i*M/4+M/2, (M/4)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream1));

}
```

Assuming, for the sake of illustration, that each operation will take the same amount of time, then the overlap between memory transfers and computation will be something like:

```
stream0    stream1    
a H2D
           a H2D
b H2D
kernel     b H2D
c D2H      kernel
           c D2H
...
```

In this example (whose aim is just to sketch the general idea), it has been assumed that the device has no concurrent bi-directional data transfer capability. Other schemes may result more efficient when this capability is available.